# how to check field values are same value in database

Tags: mysql, laravel-4

I have a database table WysTeacherattendance  -table fields are(id  t_adate t_amonth t_ayear t_attendance )

```
id  t_adate t_amonth t_ayear t_attendance   

1    15       07     2015       1   
2    15       07      2015      1   
3    15       07      2015      1       
4    15       07      2015      1           
5    15       07      2015      1       
6    15       07      2015      1       
7    15       07      2015      1           
8    15       07      2015      1       
9    15       07      2015      1       
10   15       07      2015      1
```

i have 10 teachers and iam enter all attendances are 1, insert into database t_attendance is 1 for all 10 rows.

when im enter submit button values  go to database and redirect to another page ,before check all t_attendance is 1 or not  .

1st condition

if its all 1 go to **home page**.

```
id  t_adate t_amonth t_ayear t_attendance   

1    15       07     2015       1   
2    15       07      2015      1   
3    15       07      2015      1       
4    15       07      2015      0           
5    15       07      2015      1       
6    15       07      2015      1       
7    15       07      2015      0           
8    15       07      2015      1       
9    15       07      2015      1       
10   15       07      2015      1
```

2nd condition

if any t_attendance value is 0 then go to **attendance page.**

how to check these 2 conditions.

iam us its controller code

```
foreach ($teachers as $teacher){
                        $teacheratt = new WysTeacherattendance();
                        $teacheratt->t_auserid = $teacher->user_id;
                        $teacheratt->t_adate=$date_exploded[0];
                        $teacheratt->t_amonth=$date_exploded[1];
                        $teacheratt->t_ayear=$date_exploded[2];
                        $teacheratt->t_attendance=Input::get($teacher->user_id);
                        $teacheratt ->save();
                    } 
                    if($users = DB::table('wys_teacherattendances')
                           ->where('t_adate',$date_exploded[0])
                          ->whereIn('t_attendance', array(1))->get())
                     {return Redirect::route('GetTeachersearchAttendence')
                        ->with('success',' teacher exist');  
                     }
                     if($users = DB::table('wys_teacherattendances')
                           ->where('t_adate',$date_exploded[0])
                          ->where('t_attendance', '=',0)->get())
                     {return Redirect::route('AddTeacherabsentReason',$date_exploded[0])
                       ->with('success',' teacher exist');  
                    }         
                }`

but only work this condition `if($users = DB::table('wys_teacherattendances')
                           ->where('t_adate',$date_exploded[0])
                          ->whereIn('t_attendance', array(1))->get())
                     {return Redirect::route('GetTeachersearchAttendence')
                        ->with('success',' teacher exist');  
                     }
```

how solve it??

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if($users == DB::table('wys_teacherattendances')
    ->where('t_adate',$date_exploded[0])
    ->whereIn('t_attendance', array(1))->get())
{return Redirect::route('GetTeachersearchAttendence')
    ->with('success',' teacher exist');  
}
```

for compare result, you must use ==, not = (= assigning value, not checked the value)

I think you must change all "=" you have typed with "=="

I only give the idea
You can check the number of that teacher

```
$teacher_number = "SELECT COUNT(teacher) from teacher"
```

You can check the number of that attendance

```
$attendance = "SELECT COUNT(attendance) from attendance where 
attendance = 1 and date = yourdate"

if $teacher_number == $attendance
    redirect home.page
else if $teacher_number > $attendance
    redirect attendance.page
```

Comment: its not work... how to check t_attendance field values all are 1 or not?? if 1  redirect to home page.. else redirect attendance page..

Comment: thank you sir....$teacher_number = "SELECT COUNT(teacher) from teacher" $attendance = "SELECT COUNT(attendance) from attendance where 
attendance = 1 and date = yourdate"

if $teacher_number == $attendance
    redirect home.page
else if $teacher_number > $attendance
    redirect attendance.page